# Finding the percentage of change of 30 meter resolution raster within buffer area

Tags: raster, point, arcgis-pro, buffer, land-cover

How could I find the percentage of change for each buffer area in the image below using ArcGIS Pro 2.5.0?

I want to be able to show the percentage of change for each INDIVIDUAL and "unique" buffer/circle so that I can create a histogram or some type of similar graph. The blue pins are the "Point Locations", the general circles are 250-meter buffers from the point locations, the yellow cells are equal to change, and the dark black cells are equal to no change:

[image]

Comment: Yes I do, I have access to that and spatial analyst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Zonal Histogram (Spatial Analyst)`. You can define zones either by an integer raster or a feature layer (your buffers of 250m).

See: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/zonal-histogram.htm

Optionally it can create a graph automatically.
Make sure there are no overlapping features.

Comment: So I was able to use Zonal Histogram (Spatial Analyst) with the "Zones as rows in output table" checked but my output table only shows 99 OBJECTID's, however I have 967 individual buffered circles that I am trying to get percentage of change. Does Zonal Histogram only evaluate a certain amount of OBJECTID's or does it have a limit of what it outputs?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I checked the documentation again and it does not point to such a thing. Sorry, I cant help you further at this moment.